# Java: How to copy the contents of a txt file into another txt file without ruining how the lines look (scanner)?

Tags: java, file, text, io, java.util.scanner

I have an assignment related to the file class, scanner and printwriter. The majority of the assignment should be complete, its just one part that I cant solve. For context, these are the instructions

**"Write a program to edit text files for extra blanks. The program will replace any string of two or more blanks with a single blank. Your program should work as follows: Create a temporary file. Copy from the file to the temporary file but do not copy extra blanks. Copy the contents of the temporary file back into the original file. Use a method (or methods) in the class File to remove the temporary file. You will also want to use the lass File for other things in your program. The temporary file should have a name that is different from all existing files so that the existing files are not affected (except for the file being edited). Your program will ask the user for the name of the file to be edited. However, it will not ask the user for the name of the temporary file but instead, it will generate the name within the program. You can generate the name any way that is clear and efficient. One possible way to generate the temp file is to start with an unlikely name such as "TempX", and to append a character, such as
X' until a name is found that does not name an existing file.**

[image]
This is an image of the file we have to fix, we need to copy the contents of this file into a temporary file, then remove any extra spaces in the sentences without ruining the format. Then once its fixed, we copy the conents back into the original testFile and delete the temporary file.

[image]

I got close, I am able to remove any extra white spaces, however the title is wrong. What can I use to preserve the format and remove any extra blanks?

Here is my code if you need to look:

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgramA4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file;
        int i = 1;
        String FileName = "temporary_file"; // name of the temporary file

        do {

            file = new File("C:\\Users\\emili\\Eclipse-Workplace-2\\Assignment4\\" + FileName + ".txt");

            if (!file.exists()) // if the name for Filename (in this case "temporary_file") already exists,
                                // then create a new file anyway but with an "x" next to it. The loop will work
                                // no matter how many file names are there.
                break;

            if (file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("That file already exists, creating a new one with an extra 'x' on it!");
                // file.delete();
                FileName = FileName + "_x";
                file = new File("C:\\Users\\emili\\Eclipse-Workplace-2\\Assignment4\\" + FileName + ".txt");
            }

        } while (file.exists()); // loop if file exist

        //
        PrintWriter tempfile_printwriter = null;
        PrintWriter testfile_printwriter = null;
        Scanner tempfile_scanner = null;
        Scanner testfile = null;
        String line = null;
        //

        try { // crate a printwriter to add words into the temp file, testfile is a scanner to
                // get all the words from testfile. Temp file scanner is used later.
            tempfile_printwriter = new PrintWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\emili\\Eclipse-Workplace-2\\Assignment4\\" + FileName + ".txt"));

            tempfile_scanner = new Scanner(
                    new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\emili\\Eclipse-Workplace-2\\Assignment4\\" + FileName + ".txt"));

            testfile = new Scanner(
                    new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\emili\\Eclipse-Workplace-2\\Assignment4\\testfile.txt"));

            while (testfile.hasNextLine()) {
                // while loop removes empty or extra spaces, preserves format.
                // Copies contents of testfile.txt into the temporary_file.
                line = testfile.nextLine();
                line = line.replaceAll("  +", " ");

                tempfile_printwriter.println(line);
            }
            tempfile_printwriter.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("IO ERROR");
        }

        String newLine = null;
        try {
// printwriter for testFile so we can write inside the file and print the corrected version from temp file. 
            testfile_printwriter = new PrintWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\emili\\Eclipse-Workplace-2\\Assignment4\\testfile.txt"));
            while (tempfile_scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                newLine = tempfile_scanner.nextLine();
                testfile_printwriter.println(newLine);
            }
            testfile_printwriter.close();
            testfile.close();
            tempfile_scanner.close();
            file.deleteOnExit();
            // CLOSES ALL STREAMS, DELETES TEMPORARY FILE

        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("IO ERROR");
        }

    }
}
```

Please keep in mind, I am trying to use the resources I have at this level of Java.

Comment: In what way is the title wrong?  Your instructions were to replace any series of two or more spaces with a single space.  It looks to me like you've done that.  What have I failed to understand?

Comment: Read/write the first line outside of the while loop.

Comment: Thank you, before while (testfile.hasNextLine()) { 
   //while loop removes empty or extra spaces, preserves format. 
   //Copies contents of testfile.txt into the temporary_file. 
   line = testfile.nextLine();     
   line = line.replaceAll("  +"," ");

  tempfile_printwriter.println(line);
  }

Comment: I needed to add line = testfile.findInLine("                                            A SCANDAL IN BOHEMIA ");
  tempfile_printwriter.print(line);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, it seems that user camickr gave me the idea that I needed. I had to go and find more methods that I could use so I used findInLine in order to print the line inside the file before the while loop.

```
line = testfile.findInLine("                                            A SCANDAL IN BOHEMIA ");
        tempfile_printwriter.print(line);


//Then the while loop starts.

    while (testfile.hasNextLine()) { 
            //while loop removes empty or extra spaces, preserves format. 
            //Copies contents of testfile.txt into the temporary_file. 
            line = testfile.nextLine();     
            line = line.replaceAll("  +"," ");

        tempfile_printwriter.println(line);
        }
        tempfile_printwriter.close();
        
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception ) {
            System.out.println("IO ERROR");
        }
```